# как присвоить значение из async метода в List?

Tags: flutter

вот класс `Asd`:

```
class Asd{
  String aa;
  String bb;

  Asd(this.aa, this.bb);
}
```

вот мой лист:

```
List<Asd> dsa;
```

как теперь мне присвоить этому листу значение полученного из метода ниже:

```
  sss() async{
    var response = await http.get(urlVar);
    var result = json.decode(response.body);
    var ttt = List<Asd>();
    for(var u in result){
      Asd ccc = Asd(u['country'], u['text']);
      ttt.add(ccc);
    }
      dsa = ttt;
  }
```

присвоил таким образом, но когда нажимаю на кнопку `onPressed(){print(dsa);}` консоль показывает: `null` , то есть, не присваивается,  помогите, я застрял в этом моменте

Answer (score 0):

Не тестировал, возможно не будет работать...
Метод `set` в классе `Asd` необходимо доработать для ваших нужд.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Main{
  sss(){
    var ttt = Asd.get();
    var dsa = Asd.set(ttt);

    print(dsa);
  }
}

class Asd{
  String aa;
  String bb;

  Asd(this.aa, this.bb);

  factory Asd.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Asd(json['aa'], json['bb']);
  }


  static Future<List<Asd>> get() async {
    var response =
        await Api.get('api/v1/...');

    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    final items = (responseJson["items"] as List).map((i) => new Post.fromJson(i));

    return items.toList();
  }

  static List<Asd> set(List<Asd> list){
    var temp = List<Asd>;

    for(var u in list){
      Asd ccc = Asd(u['country'], u['text']);
      temp.add(ccc);
    }

    return temp;
  }
}

class Api{
  static const String BaseUrl = 'http://api.com/';

  static Future<http.Response> get(String url){
    return http.get(BaseUrl + url);
  }
}
```